# minikube start on windows is failing with error - timeout acquiring mutex

Tags: kubernetes, minikube

Trying to start minikube on windows 10 but it is failing with below given error. Tried deleting context, config file itself and recreated it but issue persists.

X Failed to setup kubeconfig: writing kubeconfig: `Error writing file C:\Users\<user name>/.kube/config: error acquiring lock for C:\Users\<user name>/.kube/config: timeout acquiring mutex`

Thank you.

Comment: Is it a new setup, or existing one?  

I have just installed minikube (with minikube-installer.exe) according to https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/  , rebooted my machine, opened `cmd` and ran `minikube start --vm-driver=virualbox` . It works. How exactly you have tried installing it if that is a new setup.?

Comment: Minikube dev team has fixed it.

Answer (score 3):

I have just downloaded [minikube-windows-amd64.exe](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases/download/v1.5.2/minikube-windows-amd64.exe), copied to my `PATH` and started with `minikube start --vm-driver=virualbox`.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>minikube start --vm-driver=virtualbox
* minikube v1.5.2 on Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0.18362 Build 18362
* Downloading VM boot image ...

minikube-v1.5.1.iso: 143.76 MiB / 143.76 MiB [] 100.00% 10.15 MiB 

* Creating virtualbox VM (CPUs=2, Memory=2000MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
* Preparing Kubernetes v1.16.2 on Docker '18.09.9' ...
* Downloading kubeadm v1.16.2
* Downloading kubelet v1.16.2
* Pulling images ...
* Launching Kubernetes ...
* Waiting for: apiserver
* Done! kubectl is now configured to use "minikube"

C:\WINDOWS\system32>minikube status
host: Running
kubelet: Running
apiserver: Running
kubeconfig: Configured

C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

It seems that **the issue is with today's (Dec-11-2019) release of  v1.6.0** .

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>minikube start --vm-driver=virtualbox
* minikube v1.6.0 on Microsoft Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0.18362 Build 18362
* Selecting 'virtualbox' driver from user configuration (alternates: [hyperv])
* Tip: Use 'minikube start -p <name>' to create a new cluster, or
'minikube delete' to delete this one.
* Using the running virtualbox "minikube" VM ...
* Waiting for the host to be provisioned ...
* Preparing Kubernetes v1.17.0 on Docker '19.03.5' ...
*
X Failed to setup kubeconfig: writing kubeconfig: Error writing file
C:\Users\<username>/.kube/config: error acquiring lock for
C:\Users\<username>/.kube/config: timeout acquiring mutex
*
* Sorry that minikube crashed. If this was unexpected, we would love
to hear from you:
  - https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new/choose
```

I have submitted it on [minikube GitHub Issue Tracker](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/6058).

**EDIT 12-Dec-2019:**

v1.6.1 is now available with this bug fixed: https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/releases/tag/v1.6.1

Comment: It looks like that is quite popular issue today. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59284489/failed-to-setup-kubeconfig-when-starting-minikube

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem. Most likely is an issue of version 1.6.0 which was released today. Downgrade to 1.5.2 for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem with version 1.6.0 but it was solved after I upgraded to version 1.6.1.