# Failed to setup kubeconfig when starting minikube

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubectl, minikube

I have installed **kubectl** and **minikube** on my windows environment, but when running **minikube start** it creates the VM on vitualBox but I got this error when it trying to prepare kubernetes on Docker.

```
C:\Users\asusstrix>minikube start

* minikube v1.6.0 on Microsoft Windows 10 Home 10.0.18362 Build 18362
* Selecting 'virtualbox' driver from user configuration (alternates: [])
* Creating virtualbox VM (CPUs=2, Memory=2000MB, Disk=20000MB) ...
* Preparing Kubernetes v1.17.0 on Docker '19.03.5' ...
*
X Failed to setup kubeconfig: writing kubeconfig: Error writing file C:\Users\asusstrix/.kube/config: error acquiring lock for C:\Users\asusstrix/.kube/config: timeout acquiring mutex
*
* Sorry that minikube crashed. If this was unexpected, we would love to hear from you:
  - https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/new/choose
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the official documentation:

> To confirm successful installation of both a hypervisor and Minikube,
>   you can run the following command to start up a local Kubernetes
>   cluster:
>
> `minikube start --vm-driver=<driver_name>`
>
> For setting the --vm-driver with minikube start, enter the name of the
>   hypervisor you installed in lowercase letters where  is
>   mentioned below. A full list of --vm-driver values is available in
>   specifying the [VM driver
>   documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/learning-environment/minikube/#specifying-the-vm-driver).

So in your case it would be: `minikube start --vm-driver=<virtualbox>`

If you want ot make sure your previous steps were correct you can go through the whole [tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/tools/install-minikube/).

Please let me know if that helped.

**EDIT:**

There is a [Github thread](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/6058) showing the same issue.

Basically you still should use `minikube start --vm-driver=<driver_name>` but it will not work with v1.6.0 yet. Consider downgrading to v1.5.2 instead.

Comment: It works perfectly when upgrading from the minikube version 1.6.0 to 1.6.1. Downgrading to previous versions may also work.